# Адаптер для addHeaderView в ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

У меня есть 2 разметки для Айтемов ListView. Так вот один используется как Хидер для ListView а другой в остальных. То есть вторая Разметка берет данные с адаптера, где соответственно инициализируются поля.

**Мой адаптер:**

```
public class DetailsAdapter  extends ArrayAdapter<TicketObjects> {
private int resource;
private LayoutInflater  inflater;
private Context context;
public DetailsAdapter ( Context ctx, int resourceId, List<TicketObjects> objects) {
    super( ctx, resourceId, objects );
    resource = resourceId;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from( ctx );
    context=ctx;
}
@Override
public View getView ( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {
    convertView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate( resource, null );
    TicketObjects ticketObjects = getItem( position );

    TextView depTransferCity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTransferCity);
    TextView detDepartTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.detDepartTime);
    TextView detDepartDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.detDepartDate);
    TextView detArriveTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.detArriveTime);
    TextView detArriveDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.detArriveDate);
    TextView depDepartCity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.depDepartCity);
    TextView detDepartAirport = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.detDepartAirport);
    TextView detArriveCity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.detArriveCity);
    TextView detArriveAirport = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.detArriveAirport);
    TextView detFlight = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.detFlight);
    ImageView airlineLogo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.detAirportLogo);

    depTransferCity.setText(ticketObjects.getTransferCity());
    detDepartTime.setText(ticketObjects.getDepartTime());
    detDepartDate.setText(ticketObjects.getDepartDate());
    detArriveTime.setText(ticketObjects.getArriveTime());
    detArriveDate.setText(ticketObjects.getArriveDate());
    depDepartCity.setText(ticketObjects.getDepartCity());
    detDepartAirport.setText(ticketObjects.getDepartAirport());
    detArriveCity.setText(ticketObjects.getArriveCity());
    detArriveAirport.setText(ticketObjects.getArriveAirport());
    detFlight.setText(ticketObjects.getFlight());
    airlineLogo.setImageResource(ticketObjects.getAirlineLogo());

    return convertView;
}
}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivityextends Activity {

private ListView lvDetails;
private Context ctx;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ticket_details);
    ctx=this;
    List<TicketObjects> ticketObjectses = new ArrayList<>();
    ticketObjectses.add(new TicketObjects("Бишкек", "Манас", "Ош", "Аэропорт Оша", "FRU", "13:45", "16.09.2015", "OSS", "13:45", "16.09.2015", "Almaty", "1ч 15мин", "15000", R.drawable.logo_flyduba, "Рейс: 543"));
    ticketObjectses.add(new TicketObjects("Ош", "Аэропорт Оша", "Новосибирск", "Толмачево", "OSS", "15:43", "16.09.2015", "OVB", "17:45", "16.09.2015", "Astana", "1ч 25мин", "16000", R.drawable.logo_kazak, "Рейс: 543"));
    ticketObjectses.add(new TicketObjects("Алматы", "Алматы", "Москва", "Домодедово","ALA","11:54","16.09.2015","DME","12:44","16.09.2015","Novosibirsk", "2ч 15мин","13000", R.drawable.logo_pegasus_logo, "Рейс: 543"));

    lvDetails = ( ListView ) findViewById( R.id.lvDetails);

    ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.ticket_details_header_item,lvDetails,false);

    lvDetails.addHeaderView(header);
    lvDetails.setAdapter(new DetailsAdapter(ctx, R.layout.ticket_details_item, ticketObjectses));
}
}
```

**Разметка для хидера:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/leftPadding"
    android:layout_below="@+id/line"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:background="@drawable/layouts_border">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/iconsSize"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/leftPadding"
        android:background="#e8e8e8"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/rightPadding">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Бишкек"
            android:id="@+id/detTitleArriveCity"
            android:textColor="@color/otherTextColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/mainLargeSize"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Нью-Йорк"
            android:id="@+id/detTitleArriveCity"
            android:textColor="@color/otherTextColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/mainLargeSize"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/smallIconSize"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/smallIconSize"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_depart"
            android:padding="@dimen/rightPadding"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/rightPadding"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/rightPadding" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="35ч 00м"
            android:id="@+id/detTotalDuration"
            android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/mainSmallSize"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/leftPadding"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/text_margin">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/rightPadding"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/smallIconSize"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/smallIconSize"
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:src="@drawable/from"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/smallIconSize"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/smallIconSize"
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:src="@drawable/punktir"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_marginTop="-5dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/smallIconSize"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/smallIconSize"
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:src="@drawable/to"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="-5dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/rightPadding"
            android:layout_weight="2">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="09:50"
                android:id="@+id/detDepartTime"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:textColor="@color/otherTextColor"
                android:textSize="@dimen/mainLargeSize" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="12.06.2016"
                android:id="@+id/detDepartDate"
                android:layout_below="@+id/detDepartTime"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/rightPadding"
                android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                android:textSize="@dimen/mainMiddleSize" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="11:40"
                android:id="@+id/detArriveTime"
                android:layout_below="@+id/detDepartDate"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:textColor="@color/otherTextColor"
                android:textSize="@dimen/mainLargeSize" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="13.06.2016"
                android:id="@+id/detArriveDate"
                android:layout_below="@+id/detArriveTime"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                android:textSize="@dimen/mainMiddleSize" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/rightPadding"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Бишкек"
                android:id="@+id/depDepartCity"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:textColor="@color/otherTextColor"
                android:textSize="@dimen/mainLargeSize" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Манас"
                android:id="@+id/detDepartAirport"
                android:layout_below="@+id/depDepartCity"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/rightPadding"
                android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                android:textSize="@dimen/mainMiddleSize" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Москва"
                android:id="@+id/detArriveCity"
                android:layout_below="@+id/detDepartAirport"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:textColor="@color/otherTextColor"
                android:textSize="@dimen/mainLargeSize" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Шереметьево"
                android:id="@+id/detArriveAirport"
                android:layout_below="@+id/detArriveCity"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                android:textSize="@dimen/mainMiddleSize" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/stndHeight"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/leftPadding">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Рейс: AN565"
            android:id="@+id/detFlight"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@color/otherTextColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/mainLargeSize" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/detAirportLogo"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_flyduba"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Разметка для остального:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/leftPadding"
        android:background="#e8e8e8"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/smallIconSize"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/smallIconSize"
            android:id="@+id/locIcon"
            android:src="@drawable/location"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="@dimen/leftPadding" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Пересадка:"
            android:id="@+id/textviewTransfer"
            android:layout_weight="3" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tvTransferCity"
            android:textColor="@color/otherTextColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/mainLargeSize"
            android:layout_weight="3" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/leftPadding"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/text_margin"
        android:id="@+id/centerlayout">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/rightPadding"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/smallIconSize"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/smallIconSize"
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:src="@drawable/from"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/smallIconSize"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/smallIconSize"
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:src="@drawable/punktir"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_marginTop="-5dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/smallIconSize"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/smallIconSize"
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:src="@drawable/to"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="-5dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/rightPadding"
            android:layout_weight="2">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="09:50"
                android:id="@+id/detDepartTime"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:textColor="@color/otherTextColor"
                android:textSize="@dimen/mainLargeSize" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="12.06.2016"
                android:id="@+id/detDepartDate"
                android:layout_below="@+id/detDepartTime"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/rightPadding"
                android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                android:textSize="@dimen/mainMiddleSize" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="11:40"
                android:id="@+id/detArriveTime"
                android:layout_below="@+id/detDepartDate"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:textColor="@color/otherTextColor"
                android:textSize="@dimen/mainLargeSize" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="13.06.2016"
                android:id="@+id/detArriveDate"
                android:layout_below="@+id/detArriveTime"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                android:textSize="@dimen/mainMiddleSize" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/rightPadding"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Бишкек"
                android:id="@+id/depDepartCity"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:textColor="@color/otherTextColor"
                android:textSize="@dimen/mainLargeSize" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Манас"
                android:id="@+id/detDepartAirport"
                android:layout_below="@+id/depDepartCity"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/rightPadding"
                android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                android:textSize="@dimen/mainMiddleSize" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Москва"
                android:id="@+id/detArriveCity"
                android:layout_below="@+id/detDepartAirport"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:textColor="@color/otherTextColor"
                android:textSize="@dimen/mainLargeSize" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Шереметьево"
                android:id="@+id/detArriveAirport"
                android:layout_below="@+id/detArriveCity"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                android:textSize="@dimen/mainMiddleSize" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/stndHeight"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/leftPadding">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Рейс: AN565"
            android:id="@+id/detFlight"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@color/otherTextColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/mainLargeSize" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/detAirportLogo"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_flyduba"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Сейчас разметка для Хидера ничего отображает, то есть вообще нет данных кроме TextView. А вторая разметка как видете инициализирутся в Адаптере и у него есть данные.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос:** Как хидеру инициализировть и отображать данные с массива которая в MainActivity? Где должна происходить инициализация ХИдера?

Answer (score 1):

Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978359/using-listview-how-to-add-a-header-view#comment31971342_7978427) пишут, что до андроида версии 4.4 `header` надо добавлять **после** установки адаптера

Comment: Спасибо за информацию... Но проблема в том, что он отображается, то есть компоненты. Но ничего не выводит потому что не инициализирован. вопрос: где нужно инициализировать?

Comment: @Omuradil, не очень понимаю проблему... Что он не выводит и что должен?..

Comment: @Omuradil, если вопрос в том, где получить его вьюхи и назначить им текст/фон, то следующей же строкой после его создания.